# How to enhance the performance of Java application with JSF front-end & SOAP webservice as a backend

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, soap

We have a JAVA application which uses **JSF framework** in the front-end(xhtml pages) and SOAP web services in the backend. To consume the **SOAP webservice**  I am using **wsimport** tool*(JAX-WS portable artifacts)*.

Now the application is **hosted in a clustered environment**. Request is sent to the **Apache load balancing server** which in turn call the **two app servers**(Where the application is deployed) **each having five instances**.

The performance is good when up to 10-15 users access the application simultaneously. But, when the number of users increases for example **20-25 users**, The response time of the **application is very slow**. The SOAP response is very quick but the application could not handle the **huge data load**.

Can anyone advice how to handle this and improve the application's performance.

Comment: This requires a full code review. Hire a consultant. Stack Overflow is at least not the right place for that, sorry. All we could say is to just run a profiler to nail down the inefficiences in your codebase. I can only add that most common starter's mistake is misunderstanding and/or abusing variable scoping. Your starting points would then be among others http://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked a question in a bit different way. Finally figured the answer.

1) Removed the unwanted maven plugins and upgraded the maven version.

2) Used XML paresrs for webservice calls, instead of custom webservice libraries.

3) Removed unused JAR files.

4) increased the Java Heap Space to handle huge Data.

5) Upgraded the version of JBOSS server.

After this, I could see a considerable increase in the performance of the application.